# mysql where inet_aton like %...%

Tags: mysql, search, ip, where-clause

In my DB I store IP (ipv4) with INET_ATON

```
<?php
$ip = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, $_SERVER[ 'REMOTE_ADDR' ] );
mysqli_query( $con, "INSERT INTO table ( ip ) VALUES ( INET_ATON( '$ip' ) )" );
```

Then, to search a "normal ip" I do the following

```
SELECT *  FROM table WHERE ip = INET_ATON ('31.165.84.4')
```

But how can I search only a part of the ip? for example:

```
SELECT *  FROM table WHERE ip LIKE INET_ATON ('31.165.84') // not working
SELECT *  FROM table WHERE ip LIKE INET_ATON ('%31.165.84%') // not working
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use  the reverse function INET_NTOA

and you have only partial match ( '31.165.84') (missing the last digit)

```
 SELECT *  FROM table WHERE INET_NTOA(ip) = '31.165.84.4'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a query like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE ip 
  BETWEEN INET_ATON('31.165.84.0')
  AND INET_ATON('31.165.84.255');
```

**Test**

```
SELECT  
if( INET_ATON('31.165.84.2') -- ip in Table
  BETWEEN INET_ATON('31.165.84.0') -- Min Addr.
  AND INET_ATON('31.165.84.255'),1,0); -- Max Addr.
```

**sample**

```
mysql> SELECT
    -> if( INET_ATON('31.165.84.2')
    ->   BETWEEN INET_ATON('31.165.84.0')
    ->   AND INET_ATON('31.165.84.255'),1,0) as cmp;
+-----+
| cmp |
+-----+
|   1 |
+-----+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
mysql> SELECT
    -> if( INET_ATON('31.165.84.177')
    ->   BETWEEN INET_ATON('31.165.84.0')
    ->   AND INET_ATON('31.165.84.255'),1,0) as cmp;
+-----+
| cmp |
+-----+
|   1 |
+-----+
1 row in set (0,01 sec)

mysql>
mysql> SELECT
    -> if( INET_ATON('31.165.85.177')
    ->   BETWEEN INET_ATON('31.165.84.0')
    ->   AND INET_ATON('31.165.84.255'),1,0) as cmp;
+-----+
| cmp |
+-----+
|   0 |
+-----+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: This assumes that the OP wishes to search for a range, and not another pattern.